# R-function to repeat a command

Tags: r, function

I am running a command statement that looks like this:

```
t.out=setx(z.out,
            race1=1
            race2=0,
            race3=0,
            influence1=0,
            influence2=0,
            influence3=0,
            influence4=0,
            influence5=0
            influence6=0,
            influence7=0)
s.out=sim(z.out, x=t.out)
ev=s.out$qi[[1]]
ev.mean=mean(ev)
ev.ci = quantile(ev, c(0.025,0.975))
race1.infl0=c(ev.mean,ev.ci)
```

All of the variables above are dummy variables, I need to run this statement for all possible combinations of race and influence for example, the next variable would be as follows:

```
t.out=setx(z.out,
                race1=1
                race2=0,
                race3=0,
                influence1=1,
                influence2=0,
                influence3=0,
                influence4=0,
                influence5=0,
                influence6=0,
                influence7=0 
s.out=sim(z.out, x=t.out)
    ev=s.out$qi[[1]]
    ev.mean=mean(ev)
    ev.ci = quantile(ev, c(0.025,0.975))
    race1.infl1=c(ev.mean,ev.ci)
```

The only output of interest is the last one with race and influence numbers. Does any body have suggestions on creating functions that I can use to not type the entire combination manually? Any and all help will be appreciated.

My data set with which I created the model looks like this:

```
accessibility   race    influence   (Intercept) race1   race2   influence2  influence3  influence4  influence5  influence6  influence7  influence8  influence9  influence10 influence11 influence12
9.211988891 2   2   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5.859253249 2   5   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
9.752980715 2   6   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
3.574378438 2   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6.483454332 2   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
27.18509232 2   6   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
17.72394783 2   6   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
1.580419444 2   2   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
7.755443719 2   5   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5.636728983 2   6   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function like so:

```
myfun <- function(race1,race2,race3,influence1,influence2,influence3,influence4,influence5,influence6,influence7) {
  t.out=setx(z.out,
             race1=race1
             race2=race2,
             race3=race3,
             influence1=influence1,
             influence2=influence2,
             influence3=influence3,
             influence4=influence4,
             influence5=influence5
             influence6=influence6,
             influence7=influence7)
  s.out=sim(z.out, x=t.out)
  ev=s.out$qi[[1]]
  ev.mean=mean(ev)
  ev.ci = quantile(ev, c(0.025,0.975))
  race.infl=c(ev.mean,ev.ci)
  return(race.infl)

}
```

And then you can create the different permutations that you want to run in a data frame and create a for loop to run this function for each row in the data frame. If you provide some sample data I can demonstrate how to do this.

Comment: Hi the z.out that i am using here is a model fitted in Zelig. I have added the original dataset sample above. thanks.

Comment: You need to be more specific about the command you used to generate z.out. Zelig is a package with a lot of functions and options.